# помогите пожалуйста решить проблему js

Tags: javascript, html, json, html5

> Дан код:
>
> > Условия

```
due_date = OpenDoc(UrlFromDocID(OptInt(block.typical_development_program_id))).TopElem.tasks[0].due_date;
            if(last_block == "" || (last_block != "" && OpenDoc(UrlFromDocID(OptInt(last_block.typical_development_program_id))).TopElem.tasks[0].due_date != due_date)){       
        //if(last_block.typical_development_program_id == 6877825654678515140){
            program_mega_test = ArrayOptFirstElem(XQuery("for $elem in test_learnings where $elem/assessment_id = 6872249034465500974 and $elem/person_id = " + adapt_top.person_id + 
            " and $elem/max_score = $elem/score order by $elem/score descending return $elem"));
            if( 0 != undefined ){
```

```
<div class="switch-panel justify-space-between" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;"  id="switch-panel-mail" onclick="SwitchPanel('mail')">
                                <div>
                                    <div class="circle-progress v-middle <%if(adapt_top.custom_elems.ObtainChildByKey('access_date').value != ""){%>good<%}%>">&#10004;</div>
                                    <div class="inline-block font-size-3 font-dark-grey v-middle">Получение доступов</div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="progress-line v-middle" style="height: 0.3em; margin: 0 4em; text-align: right">
                                    <div class="current-progress" style="height: 0.3em; width: <%if(adapt_top.custom_elems.ObtainChildByKey('access_date').value != ""){%>100<%}else{%>0<%}%>%;"></div>
                                    <div class="current-progress-title font-size-2"><%if(adapt_top.custom_elems.ObtainChildByKey('access_date').value != ""){%>100<%}else{%>0<%}%>%</div>
                                    <div class="current-progress-desc font-size-2"><%if(adapt_top.custom_elems.ObtainChildByKey('access_date').value != ""){%>1<%}else{%>0<%}%>/1 выполнено</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="switch-panel-content" id="switch-panel-content-mail">
                                <p>Поздравляем, ты успешно аттестован для продажи продуктов:</p>
                                <p>✔ MoneyCare</p>
                                <p>✔ Халва</p>
                                <p>✔ Д2</p>
                                <p>✔ РГС</p>
                                <p>✔ СТОЛОТО</p>
                                <br/>
                                <p>Для получения письма с подтверждением аттестации нажми здесь:</p>
                                <div class="button" onclick="SendMail()">Получить письмо</div>
                                <br/>
                                <br/>
                                <p>Письмо придет автоматически на почту, его необходимо будет переслать с вложением на адрес эл.почты: <a href="mailto:test@test.ru">test@test.ru</a></p>
                            </div>
```

> 2 условия

```
<%
program_mega_test = ArrayOptFirstElem(XQuery("for $elem in test_learnings where $elem/assessment_id = 6872249034465500974 and $elem/person_id = " + adapt_top.person_id + 
" and $elem/max_score = $elem/score order by $elem/score descending return $elem"));
if(last_block.typical_development_program_id == 6877825654678515140 && program_mega_test != undefined ){
    %>
```

> 2 часть кода

```
<div class="switch-panel justify-space-between" style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;"  id="switch-panel-mail" onclick="SwitchPanel('mail')">
        <div>
            <div class="circle-progress v-middle <%if(adapt_top.custom_elems.ObtainChildByKey('access_date').value != ""){%>good<%}%>">&#10004;</div>
            <div class="inline-block font-size-3 font-dark-grey v-middle">Получение доступов</div>
        </div>

        <div class="progress-line v-middle" style="height: 0.3em; margin: 0 4em; text-align: right">
            <div class="current-progress" style="height: 0.3em; width: <%if(adapt_top.custom_elems.ObtainChildByKey('access_date').value != ""){%>100<%}else{%>0<%}%>%;"></div>
            <div class="current-progress-title font-size-2"><%if(adapt_top.custom_elems.ObtainChildByKey('access_date').value != ""){%>100<%}else{%>0<%}%>%</div>
            <div class="current-progress-desc font-size-2"><%if(adapt_top.custom_elems.ObtainChildByKey('access_date').value != ""){%>1<%}else{%>0<%}%>/1 выполнено</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="switch-panel-content" id="switch-panel-content-mail">
        <p>Поздравляем, ты успешно аттестован для продажи продуктов:</p>
        <p>✔ MoneyCare</p>
        <p>✔ Халва</p>
        <p>✔ Д2</p>
        <p>✔ РГС</p>
        <p>✔ СТОЛОТО</p>
        <br/>
        <p>Для получения письма с подтверждением аттестации нажми здесь:</p>
        <div class="button" onclick="SendMail()">Получить письмо</div>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <p>Письмо придет автоматически на почту, его необходимо будет переслать с вложением на адрес эл.почты: <a href="mailto:test@test.ru">test@test.ru</a></p>
    </div>
```

Функция

```
 for(i = 0; i < 7; i++ ){
        let indx = i;
    if(document.getElementById('switch-panel-' + i) != null){
            document.getElementById('switch-panel-' + i).addEventListener("click",  () => { SwitchPanel(indx); }, false);
    }
    }

function SwitchPanel(num){
    panel = document.getElementById('switch-panel-content-' + num);
    if(panel.style.display == "block"){
        panel.style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById('switch-panel-' + num).classList.remove("switch-selected");
    }
    else{
        panel.style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById('switch-panel-' + num).classList.add("switch-selected");
    }
}

function SendMail(){
    
    col = ['adapt_id'];
    arg = Array();
    arg.push('<%=adapt_id%>');

    getAction("adapt2.sendMail", col, arg,
            function () {
                var resp  = this.responseXML;
                location.reload();
            }
    );
```

> При нажатие на получения доступов

[image: При нажатие на получения доступов]

> Выдает ошибку
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> При нажатие на ошибку показывает вот этот часть кода
> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<%
program_mega_test = ArrayOptFirstElem(XQuery("for $elem in test_learnings where $elem/assessment_id = 6872249034465500974 and $elem/person_id = " + adapt_top.person_id +
" and $elem/max_score = $elem/score order by $elem/score descending return $elem"));
if(last_block.typical_development_program_id == 6877825654678515140 && program_mega_test != undefined ){
%>

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: прошу прощения но исправил оказывается проблема не тут было !